# Can I pass a Java Interface to a Play! template

Tags: java, scala, templates, playframework-2.0

I have a scala template that I pass in a Java `List<SomeConcreteClass>` and it works just fine.  The challenge I'm having at the moment is that I need this template to render not only instances of **SomeConcreteClass**, but any class that implements a Java interface.

I've created an interface:

`public interface MyInterface { /* bunch of method signatures here */ }`

and created another version of my scala template (call it **myNewInterfaceTemplate.scala.html**) to take the interface:  The top of the template looks like this:

```
@(myInterface: List[MyInterface], showColConfig: Boolean)
```

I then create a new controller action to render the template that looks similar to this:

```
public static Result newRenderPolymorphically() {
  List<MyInterface> items = 
  SomeOtherClass.findAllActiveItems(ClassThatImplementsMyInterface.class);
return ok(myNewInterfaceTemplate.render(items, false));
```

}

and then added a route to the new action that looks similar to this:

```
GET     /newRenderPolymorphically                  controllers.newRenderPolymorically()
```

When I compile the project with the new template, interface, and action, I get errors that do not point to anything in my code:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doASTORE(Tracer.java:453)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doOpcode54_95(Tracer.java:330)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doOpcode(Tracer.java:98)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:183)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:193)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:193)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:142)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:97)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMap(MethodInfo.java:417)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMapIf6(MethodInfo.java:399)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:113)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.instrument(CtBehavior.java:679)
    at play.core.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer.rewriteAccess(PropertiesEnhancer.java:152)
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1$$anonfun$apply$31.apply(PlayCommands.scala:326)
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1$$anonfun$apply$31.apply(PlayCommands.scala:326)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1.apply(PlayCommands.scala:326)
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1.apply(PlayCommands.scala:305)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf7$1.apply(Structure.scala:583)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf7$1.apply(Structure.scala:583)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm using Play 2.1.0

I'm guessing I could use inheritance and pass a concrete instance of a class that implements **MyInterface** that is a super class of all the types I want to render, but I really would like to just pass the interface to the template if this is possible.

Am I trying to do something that Play (2.1.0) doesn't allow?

Answer (score 0):

While in the process of refactoring my prototype to use inheritance instead of polymorphism, I stumbled upon the problem.  I defined a `getId()` method in my interface that appears to have created a conflict with the ebean ORM.  When I renamed this to `getAssetId()` in the interface and the implementing classes, the project would compile and the view would render the `List<MyInterface>` just fine.